# Python inheritance - can you have a default value in a parent?

Tags: python, inheritance, default, parent

If I had a parent class attribute that all of the child classes are going to inherit, can I set a default so that when the object is created, it automatically take the default from the parent class and no argument has to be given when creating it?

```
class F1(object):
   def __init__(self, sick="flu"):
       self.sick = sick

class F2(F1):
   def __init__(self, sick, cure):
       super(F2, self).__init__(sick)
       self.cure = cure

a = F2("bed rest")
print(a.sick)
print(a.cure)
```

this is just a sample bit of code to show what I mean.  I want every child to inherit the "sick" from the parent so I do not have to send that argument in when creating the object.  Is this possible?  Is there a different way of doing this same thing?  Would it be better to make "sick" a class attribute?

Comment: Also, if the child WANTS to override the parent default, is that possible as well with what I am asking?

Comment: Was this question worded poorly or unclear?

Comment: I am guessing this question might not be answered...

Comment: what's that last comment supposed to do? scare away possible contributors??

Comment: @netrate Your question did, indeed, get answered. Not only that: it even received **two** different answers. Could you please upvote/mark one of them as an _accepted answer_ if you found them helpful? I know I did.

Answer (score 4):

the problem with your code is, that you are declaring `F2.__init__` to have **two** explicit arguments, even though you only want to pass one.
If you want to be able to *optionally* override the creation argument of `F1` you need to handle that yourself (see `F3`)

```
class F1(object):
   def __init__(self, sick="flu"):
       self.sick = sick

class F2(F1):
   def __init__(self, cure):
       super(F2, self).__init__()
       self.cure = cure

class F3(F1):
   def __init__(self, cure, sick=None):
       if sick is None:
          super(F3, self).__init__()
       else:
          super(F3, self).__init__(sick)
       self.cure = cure

a = F2("bed rest")
print("%s -> %s" % (a.sick, a.cure))

b = F3("inhale")
print("%s -> %s" % (b.sick, b.cure))

c = F3(sick="curiosity", cure="none")
print("%s -> %s" % (c.sick, c.cure))
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I though about the same solution but assumed there was a simpler way of doing it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using `super` is the standard way of doing this in Python. If you want to override, just override...

```
class F2(F1):
   def __init__(self, sick, cure):
       super(F2, self).__init__(sick)
       self.cure = cure
       self.sick = sick + 1
```

Adding class attribute could be an option, depending on your need. From your description, I'd say it sounds better, because the default value of `sick` never change, and that's probably what you need.

Using class attribute does not affect overriding, because when assigning attribute on an instance, class attribute is not touched. An example:

```
>>> class F:
...     a = 1
...
>>> f1, f2 = F(), F()
>>> f2.a = 2
>>> f1.a
1
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is 5 years old, but I came across it trying to figure out a related issue and saw it has 4k views.  Just thought I'd suggest an alternative:

```
class F1(object):
   def __init__(self, sick="flu"):
       self.sick = sick

class F2(F1):
   def __init__(self, cure="bed rest", **kwargs):
       super().__init__(**kwargs)
       self.cure = cure

a = F2(cure="wait it out")
print(a.sick)   # => flu
print(a.cure)   # => wait it out

a = F2(sick="covid", cure="quarantine")
print(a.sick)  # => covid
print(a.cure)  # => quarantine

a = F2(sick="anything")
print(a.sick)  # => anything
print(a.cure)  # => bed rest
```

(Of course, above works without declaring default value for `cure` as well.)

You could also do it without calling with requiring keyword arguments like so:

```
class F1(object):
   def __init__(self, sick="flu"):
       self.sick = sick

class F2(F1):
   # Without keyword arguments, must call args in order F2(cure, sick)
   def __init__(self, cure="bed rest", *args, **kwargs):
       super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       self.cure = cure

a = F2("sleep")
print(a.sick)   # => flu
print(a.cure)   # => sleep

a = F2(sick="covid", cure="quarantine")
print(a.sick)  # => covid
print(a.cure)  # => quarantine

a = F2("sleep", "any sickness")
print(a.sick)  # => any sickness
print(a.cure)  # => sleep
```